# CSS triangle with one constant dimension

Tags: html, css, transform

I've used CSS border arrows quite regularly, but I don't know if what I want to achieve is possible with them, so I went another route and used pseudo elements instead. I know my solution relies on trigonometry but still don't know how to emplement it.

I need , regardless of the height of my .front div, to be able to maintain the 7PX width, thus, allowing for a flexible height with a fixed width:

```
.front{
    height: 20px;
    **width: 7px;**
    background-color: darkred;
    position: relative;
}
```

and that implies changing the transform angle in a mathematically controlled way:

```
.front:after{
    content: " ";
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: lightgreen;    
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);

}
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? Images are obviously out of the question, because pixellation...

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mauferrusca/NDErE/).

Comment: SOHCAHTOA - SIN = opposite / hypotenuse, COS = adjacent / hypotenuse and TAN = opposite / adjacent. You're going to have to create three extra elements for each `front`. One each to extend the height of the triangle in each direction to keep your angles straight and have the proper lengths. Theoretically, check out [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) and use his `::before` and `::after` pseudos. [This site](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) will generate the CSS for you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your [fiddle with a triangle in the top right corner](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/NDErE/4/) made purely of CSS. I'm sure that animating it is just a matter of resizing the two border widths.

```
#top_rt_tri {
    position:absolute; top:0px;right:0px;width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 60px 60px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;}
```